# how to handle the nulls in json?

Tags: json, ios4

I am using JSON in my project and am getting this data from JSON:

```js
{ "email"   : null,
  "fax"     : null,
  "upload"  : [
    { "ID"        : "80693",
      "username"  : "khatridha123",
      "name"      : "s_raju.jpg",
      "size"      : "42644",
      "extention" : ".jpg",
      "insertMethod"  : "upload",
      "insertInfo"    : "NULL",
      "created"       : "2011-09-20 06:34:10",
      "lastUpdate"    : "2011-10-18 00:30:27"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I parse this data into tableview and check if the upload field contains records or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check it with the help of the dictionary or array.. when you complete the fetching of the data that will store in a dictionary and with the help of the forkeyvalue you can get the tag value and you can store it in string and than check the string value is nil like

```
if(strvalue == nil || [strvalue isequaltostring @""])
```